# Google Apps Email, Contacts, Tasks, ScriptDB services integration

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

Please help me improve this Google Apps Script for reminding the user to contact people they haven't contacted in a while:

**Purpose:**

- Creates tasks for you to contact people you haven't talked to for a while.
- Adds a 'Touch Frequency (Days)' field to contacts - make a schedule per Contact
- New emails to/from a contact with make Task go away automatically
- "Complete" the task manually to signify a touch over a different channel (Phone, Chat, In-person)

**Known issues:**

1. 'Touch Frequency (Days)' field not appearing in Google Contacts interface
2. Sporadic execution errors "Data Storage Error", "Backend Error" - not sure why.  But try it again and it works.
3. Tasks are duplicated with each run - major issue - should we also search by task title as a backup if the task is missing (in case the DB was wiped out)?
4. Slower and more reads than necessary, perhaps?

[Code](http://code.google.com/p/touchminder/source/browse/touchMinder.js)

```
// http://code.google.com/p/touchminder
//
// Run TouchMinder() on a scheduled trigger as a Google Apps Script.
// You'll need to add an API Key for your Tasks Service integration (Easy: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_tasks, https://developers.google.com/console/help/)
//
// Creates tasks for you to contact people you haven't talked to for a while.
// Adds a 'Touch Frequency (Days)' field to contacts - make a schedule per Contact
// New emails to/from a contact with make Task go away automatically
// "Complete" the task manually to signify a touch over a different channel (Phone, Chat, In-person)
//
// Known issues:
// 'Touch Frequency (Days)' field not appearing
// Currently, this doesn't fully work.  Sporadic execution errors "Data Storage Error", "Backend Error" - not sure why.  But try it again and it works.
// Tasks are duplicated with each run - major issue
// Slower and more reads than necessary, perhaps?
function TouchMinder() {
  Logger.log('Starting TouchMinder');
  Logger.log('');

  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb(); // Get the db

  // Cursor to [] of contactTouches ({ table: 'ContactTouches', contactId: 0, lastTouch: 0, taskId: 0 })
  var contactTouches = [];   
  var queryResults = db.query({ table: 'ContactTouches' });
  while(queryResults.hasNext()) { contactTouches.push(queryResults.next()); }

  // Who am I?
  var currentUserEmailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var myId = ContactsApp.getContact(currentUserEmailAddress).getId();
  var allCurrentUserEmailAddresses = ContactsApp
    .getContact(currentUserEmailAddress)
    .getEmails()
    .map(function (ea) { return ea.getAddress().trim().toLowerCase(); });

  // Cursor to [] of contactTouches ({ table: 'ContactTouches', ownerContactId: myId, contactId: contactId, lastTouch: number, taskId: taskId }) // Cannot store Date, so store milliseconds instead
  // ownerContactId because I believe the scriptDb is shared by the domain in Google Apps accounts.  If not, no real harm, right?.
  var contactTouches = [];   
  var queryResults = db.query({ table: 'ContactTouches', ownerContactId: myId });
  while(queryResults.hasNext()) { contactTouches.push(queryResults.next()); }

  Logger.log('currentUserEmailAddresses: ' + allCurrentUserEmailAddresses.join(', '));

  // load all contacts
  var trackedContacts = loadContacts(contactTouches, myId);

  var maxDays = Math.max.apply( Math, trackedContacts.map(function (c) { return c.frequency; }) ) || 0; // What's the furthest back we should search?
  var earliestDate = new Date(); earliestDate.setDate(earliestDate.getDate() - maxDays);

  Logger.log('Found ' + trackedContacts.length + ' trackedContacts');
  Logger.log('');

  var tasklistId = getTouchMinderTaskList();
  var processedTasks = processCompletedTasksGetRemaining(tasklistId, db); // { completed: number, remaining: taskId[] }

  Logger.log('Touched ' + processedTasks.completed + ' contacts from completed tasks.');
  Logger.log('');

  Logger.log('Searching back as far as ' + earliestDate.toLocaleString());
  Logger.log('');

  var messages = new IterateMessages('in:anywhere -in:drafts'); // Iterate through ALL emails, sent & received.

  while (messages.moveNext()) {
    try {
      var message = messages.current.message;
      var thread = messages.current.thread;
      if (thread.getLastMessageDate() < earliestDate) break;

      var sender = extractRawEmailAddresses(message.getFrom())[0];
      var recipients = extractRawEmailAddresses(message.getTo() + ',' + message.getCc());
      var date = message.getDate().getTime(); // number!

      if (allCurrentUserEmailAddresses.filter(function (myEmail) { return sender === myEmail; }).length !== 0) { // Sent email        
        for (var r in recipients) {
          var recipient = recipients[r];

          var matchingContacts = trackedContacts.filter(function (tc) { // find matching contacts where the lastTouch is older than this date AND there's an email match
            return tc.contactTouch.lastTouch < date && 
              0 < tc.allEmails.filter(function (ea) { return ea === recipient }).length; });

          for (var mc in matchingContacts) // update the lastTouch
          {
            matchingContacts[mc].contactTouch.lastTouch = date;
          }
        }
      } else { // Received email
        var matchingContacts = trackedContacts.filter(function (tc) {  // find matching contacts where the lastTouch is older than this date AND there's an email match
          return tc.contactTouch.lastTouch < date && 
            0 < tc.allEmails.filter(function (ea) { return ea === sender }).length; });

        for (var mc in matchingContacts) // update the lastTouch
        {
          matchingContacts[mc].contactTouch.lastTouch = date;
        }
      }
    } catch (ex) {
        Logger.log('Error ' + ex + ' ' + message.getSubject());
        throw ex;
    }
  }

  Logger.log('Finished scanning');

  // For which tasks to remove
  var allRecentlyEmailed = trackedContacts.filter(function (tc) { 
    return tc.cutoffDate < tc.contactTouch.lastTouch &&  // lastTouch is after the cutoff for this contact
      tc.contactTouch.taskId != null; // and the taskId is not null
  });

  // For which tasks to add
  var allNewlyExpired = trackedContacts.filter(function (tc) { 
    return tc.contactTouch.lastTouch <= tc.cutoffDate && // lastTouch is before the cutoff for this contact
      (tc.contactTouch.taskId == null || // and there is no taskId
        processedTasks.remaining.filter(function (r) { return r === tc.contactTouch.taskId }).length === 0); // or the task is missing
  });

  for (var re in allRecentlyEmailed)
  {
    // delete the task
    var recentlyEmailed = allRecentlyEmailed[re];
    var task = processedTasks.remaining.filter(function (r) { return r.getId() === recentlyEmailed.contactTouch.taskId; })[0];

    if (task)
    {
      task.setDeleted(true);
      Tasks.Tasks.update(task, tasklistId, recentlyEmailed.contactTouch.taskId);
    }

    recentlyEmailed.contactTouch.taskId = null;
  }

  Logger.log('Deleted ' + allRecentlyEmailed.length + ' tasks');

  for (var ne in allNewlyExpired)
  {
    // add a task
    var newlyExpired = allNewlyExpired[ne];
    var title = 'Check in on ' + newlyExpired.contact.getFullName();
    Logger.log('Adding task "' + title + '"');
    var newTask = Tasks.newTask().setTitle(title);
    newlyExpired.contactTouch.taskId = Tasks.Tasks.insert(newTask, tasklistId).getId();
  }

  Logger.log('Added ' + allNewlyExpired.length + ' tasks');

  db.saveBatch(contactTouches, false);
};

// From and To lines in email are each presented as a raw string - we need to extract just the email address for matching to Contact email addresses.
// This takes a string of comma or semi-colon delimited email addresses (including optionally quotes full-names preceeding brackets addresses, or just naked email addresses)
// and returns an array of normalized addressed.
function extractRawEmailAddresses(addressLine)
{
  var reEmail = /\s*(?:([^"<,;]+)|(?:(?:(?:(?:"(?:""|[^"<,;])*")|[^"<,;]*)?\s*<([^"<>,;]*)>)))(?:$|,|;)/gi;
  var extracted = [];
  var captures;
  while (captures = reEmail.exec(addressLine))
  {
    extracted.push((captures[2] || captures[1]).trim().toLowerCase());
  }

  return extracted;
}

// Ensure that the TaskList exists and return the ID.
function getTouchMinderTaskList()
{
  var title = "TouchMinders";
  var allLists = Tasks.Tasklists.list().getItems();
  var id;
  for (var i in allLists) {
    if (title == allLists[i].getTitle()) {
      return allLists[i].getId();
    }
  }

  var newTaskList = Tasks.newTaskList();
  newTaskList.setTitle(title);
  return Tasks.Tasklists.insert(newTaskList).getId();
}

// Look for manually Completed Tasks and interpret that to mean that the Contact was touched by the user through another channel (Phone, Chat, in-person)
function processCompletedTasksGetRemaining(tasklistId, contactTouches, myId)
{
  var tasks = Tasks.Tasks.list(tasklistId).getItems();

  var completed = 0;
  var remaining = [];

  for (var t in tasks) {
    var task = tasks[t];
    var taskId = task.getId();
    var completion = task.getCompleted();
    if (completion)
    {
      var found = contactTouches.filter(function (ct) { return ct.taskId == taskId })[0];

      if (found) {
        var lastTouch = new Date(completion.replace(/\-/g,'\/').replace(/[T|Z]/g,' ')).getTime();
        found.lastTouch = found.lastTouch < lastTouch ? lastTouch : found.lastTouch;
        found.taskId = null;
        task.setDeleted(true);
        Tasks.Tasks.update(task, tasklistId, taskId);
        completed++;
      }
      else
      {
        remaining.push(taskId);
      }
    }
  }

  return { completed: completed, remaining: remaining };
}

// Get all contacts from ContactsApp Google Service and pair them with cached data found in contactTouches ScriptDB
function loadContacts(contactTouches, myId)
{
  // My Contacts only - perhaps later this is configurable?
  return ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts").getContacts()
    .map(function (c) {
      var touchFrequency = c.getCustomFields('Touch Frequency (Days)'); // Get the Contact's preferred Touch Frequency in Days as configured in the Google Contacts App custom field

      if (!touchFrequency) { // if there is no such setting, create one and set it to a default of 30 days
        touchFrequency = '30';
        c.addCustomField('Touch Frequency (Days)', touchFrequency);
      }

      var contactId = c.getId();
      var contactTouch = contactTouches.filter(function (ct) { return ct.contactId === contactId; })[0]; // Find the matching contactTouch

      if (!contactTouch) // if it doesn't exist, add it to the array (it will be saved to the ScriptDB at the end of the entire script execution)
      {
        contactTouch = { table: 'ContactTouches', ownerContactId: myId, contactId: contactId, lastTouch: 0, taskId: null };
        contactTouches.push(contactTouch);
      }

      var frequency = parseInt(touchFrequency, 10) || 30; // Attempt to parse the touchFrequency string as an int or default to 30 days
      var cutoffDate = new Date(); cutoffDate.setDate(cutoffDate.getDate() - frequency); // Calculate the earliest date to search for touches with this contact

      return { 
        frequency: frequency, 
        cutoffDate: cutoffDate.getTime(),
        contact: c,
        contactId: contactId,
        primaryEmail: c.getPrimaryEmail,
        allEmails: c.getEmails().map(function (ea) { return ea.getAddress().trim().toLowerCase(); }),
        contactTouch: contactTouch
      };
    });
}

/*
// IterateMessages created with the help of the Tracuer project from this source:
function* IterateMessages(searchCriteria, backwardFromDate) {
  var oldestYetObserved = (backwardFromDate || new Date()).getTime()/1000 | 0;

  while(true)
  {
    // Older seems non-inclusive, which is desirable for this purpose, otherwise we'd loop infinitely on any single result
    var batchSearchCriteria = searchCriteria + ' older:' + oldestYetObserved.toString(); 
    var threads = GmailApp.search(batchSearchCriteria, 0, 10);

    if (threads.length === 0) break;

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        yield messages[j];
      }
    }

    oldestYetObserved = threads[threads.length - 1].getLastMessageDate().getTime()/1000 | 0;
  }
};

for (var message in IterateMessages('in:anywhere'))
{
  console.log(message);
}
*/

// Lazily iterates through email messages.  
// Optionally pass any search criteria other than 'older:' for searchCriteria ex: 'in:inbox from:(john.doe@internet.com) subject:(Lunch?) has:attachment'.
// Optionally pass a Date from which to iterate backwards in time (by each Thread's most recent email date)
// Refer to the commented ECMAScript Harmony version above for basic details
function IterateMessages(searchCriteria, backwardFromDate) {
  var $that = this;
  var $arguments = arguments;
  var $state = 20;
  var $storedException;
  var $finallyFallThrough;
  var batchSearchCriteria;
  var i;
  var j;
  var messages;
  var threadMessages;
  var oldestYetObserved;
  var threads;
  var $result = {moveNext: function($yieldSent) {
      while (true) try {
        switch ($state) {
          case 20:
            oldestYetObserved = (backwardFromDate || new Date()).getTime() / 1000 | 0;
            $state = 21;
            break;
          case 21:
            if (true) {
              $state = 10;
              break;
            } else {
              $state = 19;
              break;
            }
          case 10:
            batchSearchCriteria = (searchCriteria || '') + ' older:' + oldestYetObserved.toString();
            $state = 11;
            break;
          case 11:
            threads = GmailApp.search(batchSearchCriteria, 0, 50);
            messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
            $state = 13;
            break;
          case 13:
            if (messages.length === 0) {
              $state = 14;
              break;
            } else {
              $state = 15;
              break;
            }
          case 14:
            $state = 19;
            break;
          case 15:
            i = 0;
            $state = 7;
            break;
          case 7:
            if (i < messages.length) {
              $state = 5;
              break;
            } else {
              $state = 9;
              break;
            }
          case 4:
            i++;
            $state = 7;
            break;
          case 5:
            threadMessages = messages[i];
            $state = 6;
            break;
          case 6:
            j = 0;
            $state = 2;
            break;
          case 2:
            if (j < threadMessages.length) {
              $state = 0;
              break;
            } else {
              $state = 4;
              break;
            }
          case 1:
            j++;
            $state = 2;
            break;
          case 0:
            $result.current = { thread: threads[i], message: threadMessages[j] };
            $state = 1;
            return true;
          case 9:
            oldestYetObserved = threads[threads.length - 1].getLastMessageDate().getTime() / 1000 | 0;
            $state = 21;
            break;
          case 19:
            $state = 23;
          case 23:
            return false;
          case 22:
            throw $storedException;
          default:
            throw "invalid state in state machine " + $state;
        }
      } catch ($caughtException) {
        $storedException = $caughtException;
        switch ($state) {
          default:
            throw $storedException;
        }
      }
    }};
  return $result;
}

// Quickly reset the taskId for all ContactTouches
function reset() {
  var currentUserEmailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var myId = ContactsApp.getContact(currentUserEmailAddress).getId();

  var contactTouches = [];  
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();  
  var queryResults = db.query({ table: 'ContactTouches', ownerContactId: myId });

  while(queryResults.hasNext()) { var next = queryResults.next(); next.taskId = null; contactTouches.push(next); }

  db.saveBatch(contactTouches, false);
}

// Slowly delete the ScriptDB items one at a time (might affect all domain users!)
function deleteAll() {
   var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
   while (true) {
     var result = db.query({}); 
     if (result.getSize() == 0) {
       break;
     }
     while (result.hasNext()) {
       db.remove(result.next());
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple of points to make this more readable and maintainable:

---

It has **Magic Numbers** everywhere:

```
switch ($state) {
      case 20:
```

Use constants / comment what the values mean. You will probably come back to this and it will be very hard to track down what all the values mean.
For example:

```
var AWESOME_STATE_OF_AWESOMENESS = 23;


switch ($state) {
    case AWESOME_STATE_OF_AWESOMENESS:
        //...
        break;
    case HORRIBLE_FAIL:
```

---

Your code reads very **horizontal**. There is a lot of code all on one line. Its like trying to read a paragraph squished into one sentence.

```
while(queryResults.hasNext()) { var next = queryResults.next(); next.taskId = null; contactTouches.push(next); }
```

Sentences have full stops and paragraphs. Javascript has semicolons and newlines. The compiler will ignore white space so it is perfectly normal to use it. If you are trying to save bandwidth down the line then use a minifier.

```
while(queryResults.hasNext()) 
{
    var next = queryResults.next();
    next.taskId = null;
    contactTouches.push(next);
}
```